# I can't properly get a refference to a ToggleButton from a row in my ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am having difficulties setting `OnCheckedChangeListener` callback on my `ToggleButton` which is in one of rows of my list view. When I try to access the ToggleButton by using its resource id, it doesn't return null. It does return the toggle button. However, it is like that the returned refference doesn't belong to what I wanted. Here is my layout of one of the rows of my list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mac_address"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton123456"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the MainActivity's layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bora.advancedlistview.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/mac_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code I have written to set my listview up and to try accessing the second row's ToggleButton.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] macAddresses = new String[] {
                "a1:23:34:6f:2b",
                "5f:4a:8c:00:5b"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_layout,
                R.id.mac_address, macAddresses);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mac_list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        View row = adapter.getView(1, null, listView);
        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggle);

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't get some kind of null pointer exception. But there is also nothing happens when I click on the second toggle button. It should print the value of `isChecked` but nothing happens.

Also, last but not least, I would like to be able to change the state of one toggle button programmaticaly. But the problem is that it doesn't render the change to the screen. Example:

```
((ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.togge)).toggle();
```

The change doesn't get render on the screen. Do I have to manually refresh? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Is the "1" as a parameter to `getView` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `ArrayAdapter`, override the `getView` method, and add the  `OnCheckedChangedListener` for the buttons there:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] macAddresses = new String[] {
            "a1:23:34:6f:2b",
            "5f:4a:8c:00:5b"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, R.id.mac_address, macAddresses);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mac_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

MyArrayAdapter

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects){
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        final int POSITION = position;

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println("Button " + POSITION + ": " + isChecked);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```